# jQuery AJAX Autocomplete not working when trying to make it dynamic

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have my autocomplete working fine if there is hard coded data being fed into it. My PHP is returning a JSON result. I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group bgcolor">
  <label for="send_to">Direct to: </label><input type="text" name="send_to" id="send_to" class="form-control send_to typeahead" placeholder="Leave blank normally">
</div>
```

Jquery

```
        $('.typeahead').typeahead({
          source: {
              groupName: {
               ajax({
                url: 'scripts/order_messaging.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify({action: 'autocomplete_to_user', query:query}),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(data)
                {
                 result($.map(data, function(item){
                  return item;
                 }));
                }
              })
            },
         },
         debug: true
        });
```

PHP

```
//autocomplete user name for user_to
if ( $_POST['action'] == 'autocomplete_to_user' ) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('select * from login where username like :query');
    $stmt->bindValue('query', '%'.$_POST['query'].'%');
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = array();
    while($user_name = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        array_push($result, $user_name->username);
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

I think it's this line in my jQuery: `data: {action: 'autocomplete_to_user', query:query},` Maybe I have a syntax problem.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Have you checked the console for errors and the network tab to see if AJAX is actually executed and what it returns? Have you tried to log javascript variable values in the console?

Comment: I don't see it making the call to 'scripts/order_details.php' when I am typing in the field. I don't see any JS errors in the console.

Comment: According to the [docs](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/), `source` is `object|array` and you're giving it a callback. Seems you're setting up your AJAX call the wrong way. Check examples on the linked site.

Comment: I've edited my code above to show where I am trying to place a console.debug()...is this the right place/syntax?

Comment: I tried the debug: true as the docs say as well. Maybe I should just use jquery.autocomplete...

Comment: It's not a good position, it should be set at the beginning of the function. But, as I said in my previous comment, you're placing a function under `source` and it expects an object or an array. Have you read what the docs say about `source` and using AJAX for it? I believe your solution is there.

Comment: Do you mean wrapping my AJAX in the groupName object? Also, this is the tutorial I was following..https://phppot.com/jquery/bootstrap-autocomplete-with-dynamic-data-load-using-php-ajax/

Comment: That documentation site is poorly designed so I can't link to a specific part of it, but please scroll down, there's a huge table describing in details every possible parameter of `typeahead`. Find `source` there, it has details. I feel like you're just reading the top of the page.

Comment: Something like this? https://pastebin.com/x6u3tBq6 Do I need to send the JSON an object named 'users' and also what is the path for if I already have the URL set?

Comment: I don't know, I never used `.typeahead`, I only read the docs. Why don't you give all the examples a try? I'll be able to test later.

Comment: hello, have you considered using bootstrap's `typeahead` instead of jQuery's? or is it a requirement? bootstrap's is so much easier to setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after much trial and error I got an autocomplete working using jQuery .autocomplete.

I don't know what I was doing wrong with the typeahead but the documentation was hard to understand (probably because of my limited experience with jQuery).

To all those in the future that need some help with this; here is a tutorial I found that was helpful: [jquery ui autocomplete tutorial](https://makitweb.com/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-php-and-ajax/)

Thank you to everyone

Answer (score 1):

As per [jQuery Ajax Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), `dataType: 'json'` evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object.

You need to stringify your data by using `JSON.stringify({action: 'autocomplete_to_user', query:query})` before you send it to PHP. Also, you need to add header `Content-Type: 'application/json'` that tells you PHP code that request data is JSON. You can do this by adding `contentType: 'application/json'` in your Ajax settings.

Your final jQuery code would look like this:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
  source: function(query, result)
  {
   $.ajax({
    url: 'scripts/order_messaging.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({action: 'autocomplete_to_user', query:query}),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(data)
    {
     result($.map(data, function(item){
      return item;
     }));
    }
  })
 }
});
```

Refer to [jQuery Ajax Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for mode details.
Hope this helps!

EDIT:

You need to update your PHP code to read JSON. Please refer to this [link](https://www.stevenrombauts.be/2018/06/read-json-request-data-with-php/).
Your PHP Code should look like this:

```
<?php
    // Read the input stream
    $body = file_get_contents("php://input");

    // Decode the JSON object
    $object = json_decode($body, true);
    //autocomplete user name for user_to
    if ( $object ['action'] == 'autocomplete_to_user' ) {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('select * from login where username like :query');
        $stmt->bindValue('query', '%'.$object['query'].'%');
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = array();
        while($user_name = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            array_push($result, $user_name->username);
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
?>
```

Comment: I tried your code and it's not working for me. I've tried placing console.debug() in different areas of the code and cant get it to send anything to the console. The syntax has proven difficult for me. I don't know when I should be doing ; to end a line verses a , etc

Comment: There is absolutely no need to stringify the data *unless* you're setting `contentType: 'application/json'`.

Comment: I think you need to change your PHP code to read JSON. Please refer to this [link](https://www.stevenrombauts.be/2018/06/read-json-request-data-with-php/) @mongoose00318

Comment: :\ yea that's still not working @RaviDesai I don't even see it making a call in the network tab when inspecting. It should be making a call each time I type something into the input field, right?

Comment: Why do you keep insisting that this is a problem with PHP not reading data? If that was true, then the AJAX would have a response with the PHP error viewable in the browser console. He doesn't need to change anything about AJAX, it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion, [the documentation](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead) has some errors. For instance, in the [demos](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/), specifically the example *Country v2* states

> A POST request will be sent with data `myKey: myValue`

when in actuality the request being sent in the example is `GET`, because it depends on the `type` key of the `ajax` object of the **first source** (*country* in this case), which is not set, thus defaulting to `GET`.

So, that being said, you really should stick to the proposed HTML structure (at least start with it, then take away stuff you don't want gradually as long as it'll let you).

HTML

```
<form id="form-country_v2" name="form-country_v2">
    <div class="typeahead__container">
        <div class="typeahead__field">
            <div class="typeahead__query">
                <input class="typeahead" name="country_v2[query]" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div class="typeahead__button">
                 <button type="submit">
                     <i class="typeahead__search-icon"></i>
                 </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('.typeahead').typeahead({
    template: "{{display}} <small style='color:#999;'>{{group}}</small>",
    source: {
      users: { //might as well be 'willy wonka', it doesn't matter
        ajax: {
          type: "POST",
          url: "scripts/order_messaging.php",

          //this is not actually needed for the request to work (reach the server),
          //this is used to access said request's returned data, it all
          //depends on how you structure the response in the server,
          //check out the php part
          path: "data.users",

          data: {
            action: 'autocomplete_to_user',
            query: 'username'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    callback: {
      //this is just to help you show the response in the html
      onResult: function(node, query, result, resultCount) {
        if (query === "") return;

        var text = "";

        if (result.length > 0 && result.length < resultCount) {
          text = "Showing <strong>" + result.length + "</strong> of <strong>" + resultCount + '</strong> elements matching "' + query + '"';
        } else if (result.length > 0) {
          text = 'Showing <strong>' + result.length + '</strong> elements matching "' + query + '"';
        } else {
          text = 'No results matching "' + query + '"';
        }
        $('#result-container').html(text);

      },
      onInit: function(node) { //and this is just informational
        console.log('Typeahead Initiated on ', node, node.selector);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

order_messaging.php

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'autocomplete_to_user') {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('select * from login where username like :query');
    $stmt->bindValue('query', '%' . $_POST['query'] . '%');
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = array();
    while ($user_name = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        array_push($result, $user_name->username);
    }

    echo json_encode(array(
        "status" => true,
        "error" => null,

        //here you use whatever structure you want to return the data in,
        //as long as the payload is an array ($result).
        //remember in the JS you are expecting 'data.users'?
        //this is where it's coming from
        "data" => array(
            "users" => $result,
        )
    ));
} else
    echo json_encode(array(
        "status" => true,
        "error" => null,
        "data" => array(
            "users" => [],
        )
    ));
```

HIH

Comment: I tried this and couldn't get it working either. I'm sure it works...I'm sure it's something I am doing. I just switched to using jQuery UI autocomplete and got it working. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

I've tested the library and you need to change two things in order to make it work.

1) You need to restructure the `source` parameter. You were giving it an AJAX callback which is not supported. According to the documentation, it accepts an array or an object with settings, so AJAX needs to be defined like this:

```js
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    source: {
        // source has an "ajax" property where you just need to place
        // the object with AJAX params (the one you'd normally place inside
        // an $.ajax() call)
        ajax: {
            url: 'scripts/order_messaging.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'autocomplete_to_user',
                query: query,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            path: '',
        },
    },
});
```

The `path` property of the `ajax` object is key here. It tells the `typeahead` function where to look for the data that was returned by the AJAX action. Since you're encoding a one-dimensional array of values, you need to set it to an empty string, meaning your data is in the root of the response.

If you were to return, for example, an array like `echo json_encode(['users' => $result]);` then you'd have to set the path to `'users'` (because that is the index in the response that holds your data).

2) You have to follow a strict HTML structure in order to make it work:

```html
<div class="typeahead__container">
    <div class="typeahead__field">
        <div class="typeahead__query">
            <input class="js-typeahead" name="q" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you leave out any of these elements, it doesn't trigger the functionality. This HTML structure is one of the first things they mention in the documentation.

Comment: Okay I think understand the path property now. It's for if you were sending more than one array to the page? Maybe you had more than one autocomplete field? Also, I tried your code...it's trying to fire on the page now but gives me an error about query: `Uncaught ReferenceError: query is not defined`; one the `<input class="js-typeahead">` how does it know that the class is .js-typeahead but the function refers to it as .typeahead in the jQuery selector?

Comment: It doesn't; in the first snippet I used your code, while in the second one I copied it from the docs. If you decide to use their class to select the input, you should change it to `$('.js-typeahead')`. You can always add another class of your own or an id, `'.js-typeahead'` just needs to be assigned to the input for their CSS to work. About `query` not being defined - well, where have you defined it? It's outside the scope of this answer since I've no idea where it's coming from.

Comment: I did this `query: $(this).val(),` and don't get a JS error anymore but don't see it making a request in the Network tab.

Comment: There's a special string that designates the input value should be used. Try with `query: '{{query}}'`.

Comment: Nope. I tried that earlier as well but just tried it again and it still isn't working. I sure appreciate your help though.

Comment: It worked on my machine when testing. Have you tried setting `dynamic: true` in the options of `typeahead` to ensure it's triggered on every key press?